# Generalised additive model - Python

Tags: python, curve-fitting, spline, gam

I'm trying to fit a non linear model using Generalized Additive model. How do I determine the number of splines to use. Is there a specific way to choose the number of splines? I have used a 3rd order (cubic) spline fitting. Below is the code.

```
from pygam import LinearGAM
from pygam.utils import generate_X_grid

# Curve fitting using GAM model - Penalised spline curve.
def modeltrain(time,value):
    return LinearGAM(n_splines=58,spline_order=3).gridsearch(time, value)

model=modeltrain(t1,x1)

# samples random x-values for prediction
XX = generate_X_grid(model)

#plots for vizualisation
plt.plot(XX, model.predict(XX), 'r--')
plt.plot(XX, model.prediction_intervals(XX,width=0.25), color='b', ls='--    ')
plt.scatter(t1, x1)
plt.show()
```

## This is the expected result

[image]

## Original data scatter plot

[image]

If the number of splines is not chosen correctly, then I get a incorrect fit.

Please, I would like a suggestion of methods to choose the number of splines accurately.

Answer (score 4):

Typically for splines you choose a fairly high number of splines (~25) and you let the `lambda` smoothing parameter do the work of reducing the flexibility of the model.

For your use-case I would choose the default `n_splines=25` and then do a gridsearch over the lambda parameter `lam` to find the best amount of smoothing:

```
def modeltrain(time,value):
    return LinearGAM(n_splines=25,spline_order=3).gridsearch(time, value, lam=np.logspace(-3, 3, 11))
```

This will try 11 models from `lam = 1e-3` to `1e3`.

I think your choice of `n_splines=58` is too high because it looks like it produces one spline per data-point.

If you **really** want to do a search over `n_splines` then you could do:

```
LinearGAM(n_splines=25,spline_order=3).gridsearch(time, value, n_splines=np.arange(50))
```

**Note:** the function `generate_X_grid` does NOT do random sampling for prediction, it actually just makes a dense linear-spacing of your X-values (time). The reason for this is to visualize how the learned model will interpolate.

Comment: Do you know what metric that pygam uses internally to select the best model from the gridsearch? For example, is it minimizing mean square error or mean absolute error? Can that metric be changed?

Comment: @Will.Evo yes, pyGAM uses [generalized cross validation score of the model deviance](https://github.com/dswah/pyGAM/blob/master/pygam/pygam.py#L1932). 

For models with a normal distribution, the deviance is the mean-squared error. 

Currently you can only switch the gridsearch objective to  'AIC', 'AICc', or 'GCV' / 'UBRE'...